# Consistency checkers between an Oracle DB and Solr

Tags: oracle, api, solr, consistency

We have an API that saves information to Oracle DB and then inserts the same data in Solr. Both aren't transactional, this is why we can have inconsistencies. Does anyone know a tool to check and resolve these inconsistencies between Oracle and Solr?

Answer (score 0):

There's no automated way to do it.

The way I do it is to have a program that dumps out the Oracle table in question, one line per row, and then another that dumps the Solr core in question, one line per record, and then runs diff on them.

This isn't going to be something that is going to have a one-size-fits-all approach.  Chances are your core is comprised of some data from a table, but not all the columns from that table, and probably undergoes some transformation along the way.  If you're doing a JOIN in your DIH, then that changes everything anyway.